# How To Make A Decent Drop Down Menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to add a dropdown navigation on my navigation links so far it has been great but the only issue now which I can't work out the contact is not staying next to the Community instead it's going down one line how can i force it to stay inline with everything else?

and the drop is floating to the left for some reason so how can I bring that under the dropdown (I plan to add multiple drop downs)

```
<style>
body {
    padding: 0; /* Gets rid of the automatic padding */
    margin: 0;  /*  on HTML documents */
    font-family: Lucida Grande, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#navigation {
  position: fixed;
  float:right;
  z-index:1;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
  /* Adds shadow to the bottom of the bar */
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
  /* Adds the transparent background */
  background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.8);
  color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.8);
}

#navigation a {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation a:hover {
    color: grey;
}

</style>


<style type="text/css">
    ul {
        list-style: none;padding: 0px;margin: 0px;
    }
    ul li {
     display: block;position: relative;float: left;border:1px solid #000
    }
    li ul {
        display: none;
    }
    ul li a {
        display: block;background: #000;padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;text-decoration: none;
        white-space: nowrap;color: #fff;
    }
    ul li a:hover {
        background: #f00;
    }
    li:hover ul {
        display: block; position: absolute;
    }
    li:hover li {
        float: none;
    }
    li:hover a {
        background: #f00;
    }
    li:hover li a:hover {
        background: #000;
    }
    #drop-nav li ul li {
        border-top: 0px;
    }
</style>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />
    <title>Static Navigation</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="navigation">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Social</a>
        <a href="#">Community</a>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">General Inquiries</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ask me a Question</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

    </div>


</body>
```

I added everything on one page so you can easily look at it and help with the problem

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block` to your `<li>`.

[JSfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/XGNTh/2/)

Comment: Worked even in the center ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are sure about width of navigation then dont go with "width:100%; " try to give width exactly where it supposed to be fit. Ex. Width: 900px;

Answer (score 0):

You should put the all navigation links inside li tags,

```
<body>
    <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Social</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Community</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">General Inquiries</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ask me a Question</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/L63L3/)

Comment: Thanks worked perfected ;)
only question that remains how would I float all links in to the center